# Java - loading image

Tags: java, image, resources

I am making a game and i need to load an image.Many game tutorials use the Class loader :

```
CurrentClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/image.png")
```

However, in the Oracle API, they use a File object :

```
File file = new File("res/icons.png");
```

In both cases i use `ImageIO.read()` to load the image into a BufferedImage.

What are the main differences between the two cases? Can I use both without worrying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use both, the difference is with the first approach you can load the image from a jar file and many other places. You can't do this with the second method.

You can't use the second one because a jar file is exactly that, A file. More accurately an archive. The resource loader can get items/files from within archives. The normal file/second approach can't.

Comment: You should add why you can't 'cause I'm curious.

Comment: I don't know exactly why you can't use the second one. I'm guessing it's because a jar file is exactly that, A file. More accurately an archive.  The resource loader can get items from within archives. The normal file/second approach can't.